# Unable to execute batch file on windows 7-32 bit

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to execute a batch file on win 7 .But an error come "bat. is not a valod win32 application".I have tried with SFC, but it was of no help as the same didn't got complete and some error came in it as well...:(

Comment: Please provide more details. The question was tagged 'java' , I changed to batch-file.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you enable view extensions in windows explorer and call the file something like abc.bat

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the extension to `.cmd`.
If that works you need to change the `.bat` entry in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring your registry keys for the extensions. Download the default `bat` file extension association from [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html). Then try running the batch file.

If you still have no joy make sure you are naming the file `filename.bat`, and change the file type to `All Files` to be sure, when saving it (presumably through `notepad`).

Hope this helps.